# Figured bass and ties

Tags: chords, notation, baroque-period, figured-bass, ties

How does one play figured bass when the bass line contains ties?

For example, here are the first three measures of Vivaldi's "Filiae maestae Jerusalem" ([sheet music source](https://imslp.org/wiki/Filiae_maestae_Jerusalem%2C_RV_638_(Vivaldi%2C_Antonio))).

[image]

Do I understand correctly that in measure 1, since there are no numbers to indicate an inversion, one has to play a chord consisting of C, Es and G?

Does one play only F and As in measure 2 (while still holding down the C key)? Or does one release and press again the C key in addition to F and As in measure 2? (In which case - why is there a tie between those two C-s?)

In the first half of measure 3, does one press no new keys and just continue holding C, F and As? Continue holding only C? Continue holding C, release F and As and play Es and G again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first guesses are correct: you hold the C in the bass between measure 1 and 2, and from measure 2 to measure 3, the C in the bass is held over, and the chord remains the same, C, F, Ab. Btw- "Es" in English is "Eb".

Comment: Thank you! Do you know some good internet source for learning about those kinds of details about figured bass? I looked around in Wikipedia but it just gave a very general overview without many details.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert as to what's available online.  Perhaps someone else here can make a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The tie is irrelevant to understanding the notation. If you have a figure part way through the duration of a long note, you play the new chord but you don't repeat the bass note.

That is very a common notation - for example 64 53 figures over the dominant at a cadence.

The only reason for the tie is that modern notation conventions don't have any other notation for a note that extends beyond a bar line. Up to the end of the 18th century, there *was* such a convention in some situations, so the OP's question wouldn't exist at all.